# Insert Expires Meta Tag but Still it's appearing in Search Engines Not Working

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I used 
`<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="unavailable_after: 25-Nov-2015 12:15:00 GMT" />`
for this [article](http://www.andhrawishesh.com/378-telugu-headlines-top-stories/52459-pm-modi-stays-for-75-minutes-at-amaravathi-ceremony.html).

I don't understand why it's still showing up in the Google Search results. What is the reason why my URL is still showing up?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Please include a minimal, complete sample of your code!

Comment: @T3H40 <meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="unavailable_after: 25-Nov-2015 12:15:00 GMT" /> Is this is right Tag ?  ?

Answer (score 0):

[From the Google docs](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/93977?hl=en)

> This information is treated as a removal request: it will take about a
>   day after the removal date passes for the page to disappear from the
>   search results. However, in order for the tag to function properly, it
>   must be included with your article at the time that it is first
>   crawled.

So it might take a bit more time before the removal request is honored (seeing that, at least in my timezone, Nov 25. is still ongoing), plus it will not work if you added it after Google first crawled your site.